# pkill command with sessionid is not killing entire process tree

Tags: process

I am executing the following command to stop entire process tree(i.e parent and all its child/grand-child processes) :

```
pkill -9 -s {sessionID}
```

To get sessionID I am using following command:

```
ps -o pid,sess -u <username> | grep <pid> | awk '{print $2}'
```

Sometimes pkill command kills entire process tree, but sometimes it doesn't work. Some of the child process still be running in background. Why is that so? Is there anything wrong in my logic? Is there any boundary condition missing? Are there any situations where pkill command doesn't kill child processes?

Comment: The questioner's _actual_ problem is buried, several comments in, below muru's answer.  See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212327/ .

Answer (score 0):

A process' children need not necessarily share its session ID. If that were the case, *every* process would have session ID 1. You can also try using process group IDs, but that too has the same limitation.

Walking through the process tree has the limitation that double-forked processes aren't part of the tree anymore, but might be your best bet. Examples of this method:

- [What's the best way to send a signal to all members of a process group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13481601/2072269)
- [Kill all descendant processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124148/70524)

Comment: In my case, remaining child processes have the same sessionID as that of the parent process.But still pkill didnt stop those child processes.
Why is that so?

Comment: Are you sure? Show a reproducible example, please.

Comment: Its not always reproducible. From 1000 iterations it occurs once. So i am not able to find out what is special case in that iteration.. I know only once case where if parent process got defunct then issue is reproducible.  But in my case we are not sure whether parent process got defunct or not. We are investigating on that line.


But is there any other special cases/situations where pkill command will fail to terminate entire process tree??

Comment: Is there any limitations on number of processes pkill command can kill at one time??

Comment: There are no such limitations that the documentation lists. Is the process in uninterruptible sleep?

Comment: The scenario is main process spawns child processes using system call. That child process eventually make an idl call/CORBA call to main process.  When we stop main process(by using kill -9 command) ideally that CORBA call should return and child process should also stopped.  But it was not happening. We tried to investigate where child process got stuck in CORBA call but could not find much on that line. kill command is only stopping main process. 

So to resolve that issue we used pkill command. Which is working.. But sometimes doesnt..:(   Dont knw how ti find out this